# How to reverse a sentence in c#

Tags: c#, methods, reverse, sentence

I need some guidance on how to reverse a sentence and then return to main. Either way is fine, whether the words are reversed such as "Mot am I" (I am Tom) or "Tom am I".

The user will enter any sentence with a 6 word max. Then it will be reversed. Should I use .Split or ToCharArray?  Here is what I have so far.

```
public static string Backwards() // Create Backwards Method
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("Create a sentence with at least 6 words");
            string userSentence = Console.ReadLine();


            if (userSentence.Length <= 6)
            {

            }

        }
```

Although I am pretty sure what I have isn't saying 6 or less words, it is saying 6 individual elements. Tips on how to limit a string to a certain amount of words? A lot of what I've searched has some more advanced concepts I don't quite understand yet. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should split on a space and then check the length of the array.

Comment: _"Here is what I have so far"_ - well it's good to see code, you really haven't made **any attempt** to solve the immediate problem.  Your above code could be for anything. [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might do the trick for you

```
public static string Backwards() // Create Backwards Method
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine("Create a sentence with at least 6 words");
    string userSentence = Console.ReadLine();
    //To count the number of words used split.length
    if(userSentence.Split(' ').Length <= 6)
    {
        userSentence = String.Join(" ", userSentence.Split(' ').Reverse());
    }
    return userSentence;
}
```

The [string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) method combines many strings into one. It receives two arguments: an array (or IEnumerable) and a separator string.

[Splits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) a string into substrings that are based on the **characters** in an array.

> how would I return to main method?

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string dorev = Backwards();
}
```

Comment: how would I return to main method?

Answer (score 3):

Use split and reverse:
Check split docs here:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx. There are some interesting options to the split method

```
var userSentenceArr = userSentence.split(" ");
userSentenceArr = Array.Reverse(userSentenceArr );
```

Answer (score 0):

Input string:

one two three four five

Output string:

eno owt eerht ruof evif

```
string inputString = "one two three four five";
string resultString = string.Join(" ", inputString.Split(' ').Select(x => new String(x.Reverse().ToArray())));
```